# Read XML File with JQuery and Write XML Attributes to Series of HTML Elements on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, attr

I have an image slider on a page that reads an XML file called "slider.xml" that kinda looks like this:

```
<slider>
<slide>
<link>http://www.example.com/1</link>
<path>http://image.jpg</path>
</slide>
</slider>
```

There's multiple "slide" elements but I didn't include them for space reasons.  I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
</body>
```

I want to read this XML file and write the "link" attribute to the "div" elements on an HTML page as a title attribute.  I want it to look like this:

```
<body>
<div class="slide" title="http://www.example.com/1"></div>
<div class="slide" title="http://www.example.com/2"></div>
<div class="slide" title="http://www.example.com/3"></div>
<div class="slide" title="http://www.example.com/4"></div>
<div class="slide" title="http://www.example.com/5"></div>
</body>
```

So far I have tried this but haven't had any luck:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "slider.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('slide').each(function(){
                var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                $('.slide').attr('title', url);
            }); 
        }   
    }); 
});
```

I don't have issues reading the XML file, but run into problems after I parse the XML  attributes and attach it to the various divs.  Should I create a loop and store the xml attributes in an array?  Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I cannot edit the XML or HTML.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're question is...

Comment: Pretty much, I want to write the xml attributes from a xml file to the divs of an html page as "title" attributes.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  It kinda does it but I had the problem of multiple xml attributes showing up on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your divs will have the same title since you call `$('.slide')` which select them all.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slide = $('.slide');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "slider.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('slide').each(function(i){
                var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                slide.eq(i).attr('title', url);
            }); 
        }   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have to jet, but will test in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks again, I knew i had to index each 'link' but I'm unfamiliar with the .each iterator.  Pretty handy.